# Many suspicious requests are going from my browser whenever open any site

Tags: windows, malware, web-browser, virus

Whenever I open any site there are so many suspicious request are shown in my network panel of browser. I scan my system with many antiviruses too, but still facing the same issue.
And sometimes I click any link will redirect me to a porn site or other sites. I formatted my system too but no success.

here is the one link that open rapidly [i-gency.ru](http://i-gency.ru)

[image: request list]

> **Edit**

here is the list on the extensions and plugins

[image]
[image]

Here is the one more site which block by my antivirus every time I load **Stackoverflow**

[image]

What I should do?

Comment: *I formatted my system too but no success.* then you somehow compromised it again, either one of your files is malicious, or you intentionally executed malicious software (cracks, etc) or an attacker is controlling another machine on your network and is compromising your machine every time you reinstall.

Comment: how can I find what is the exact issue?

Comment: In the meantime, you can redirect those sites to 0.0.0.0 via your hosts files until you can get things under control.

Comment: every time different site request. how many I will block?

Comment: unfortunately, we are not a malware removal forum or tech support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the URLs in your first screen capture/snippet are related to ad-providers who show ads on webpages you visit to gain revenue. The plugins and addons shown are legit.

So, its a possibility that something else is causing the traffic, possibly some ad-injecting programs or DNS hijacking. May be that's even not on your machine, but on modem/router/ISP.

Try setting your DNS servers to any of the following (how-tos described in the linked pages itself):

- Norton Connect safe : http://connectsafe.norton.com
- Open DNS            :
  https://www.opendns.com/home-internet-security/

**[edit]** Sorry, I saw your MBAM screen capture very late. It seems the issue is related to DNS itself. You must inspect your modem/router DNS configuration (log-in to those devices) and change to above entries if necessary. Make sure the firmware of modem/router are up-to date (restart modem/router later).
To verify the settings on your machine, issue the below command at command propmt (CMD.EXE):

```
ipconfig /all
```

and check the DNS server entries.

To avoid ads in webpages, use addons like ublock, adblockplus, noscript and ghoestry (for firefox)

> I scan my system with many antiviruses too, but still facing the same issue. And sometimes I click any link will redirect me to a porn site or other sites.

No security software can work 100% perfect all the time. I don't know if malware removal assistance is permitted in the community nor I'm entitled to do so, but if you suspect infection, you can get it removed and fixed freely at volunteer forums like bleepingcomputer or geekstogo.

Comment: above solution help me but looking for more. If i didn't get more I will accept your answer. +1 for answer

Comment: Lets hope it stays right. I have seen this coming back (after months).

Comment: Try connecting to internet via a different source to isolate the issue to your machine or network devices. And reset modem/router if necessary. I strongly suggest to checkout ublock and noscript addons and this tool from norton/symantec: http://www.symantec.com/avcenter/noscript.exe

Answer (score 0):

The website you mentioned appears to be a legitimate Russian language website but are not Russian or you do not read contents in Russian language, then this is an unwanted traffic for you.
These all looks like an Adware activity. You might have possibly installed a browser plugin/addon that is generating this traffic in the background.
Such fake plugins claim to be a video player or a Macromedia Flash updater but in-turn infect your browser.
Here is a link that you can follow and check if you have any such unwanted/unauthorized plugin installed:

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/it-security/how-to-check-and-configure-your-browser-plugins/

Comment: I already go through it. Please check the updated question

Comment: and I didn't want to mention porn sites ;-)

Comment: Can you check where these websites are getting Referred from ? Does this happens as soon as you launch your browser or after some time when you are doing your normal browsing.

Comment: didn't find any reference but site like cm.g.doubleclick.net/pixel?google_nid=epsilon&google_cm showing in my browser console